# How to get columns from second table only if data exists otherwise should return null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am struggling with SQL Joins concept and am facing problem when I am trying to get student attendance record. There are 3 tables that have to be used.

```
attendance a - has all student attendance
```

`st_holiday b,` - student specific holiday public list
`hol_list c` - all holiday list including weekend

There are 2 questions: 
1. I need data that gives me in_time, out_time and holiday_type to me. Student can also attend class on his holiday date(can be public holiday or weekend).

I tried below query which gives me only holiday attended dates.

```
select a.student_id, a.in_time, a.out_time, b.holiday_type
from attendance a, st_holiday b, hol_list c
where a.st_id = b.st_id
and b.holiday = c.id
and a.date = c.hol_date
```

I have also tried using `left outer join st_holiday on a.st_id = b.st_id and left outer join holiday_type on a.date = c.hol_date`
But it gives me all data and for each data holiday_type shows as Holiday/weekend, etc.

```
2. How to parameterize by date. I need to provide the data as sql script with date range parameterized. How to do the same in Sql Server. I tried using 

DECLARE from_date='2015-04-01 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE to_date='2015-04-01 00:00:00.000'

SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE .... 
AND [PI].Date BETWEEN ISNULL(@FromDate, [PI].Date) AND ISNULL(@ToDate, [PI].Date)
```

I used below link for reference. [sql server optional parameters: syntax for between clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647414/sql-server-optional-parameters-syntax-for-between-clause) 
Any help will be appreciated.

Update : Table Structure.
attendance a - primary Key ID, st_id shared with st_holiday table
`st_holiday b,` - pk is ID, holiday shared with hol_list table
`hol_list c` - hol_date can be used with date of attendance table.

Expected output:

```
St_id       IN_TIME            OUT_TIME                 Hol_type
1234  2015-08-07 08:00:00.000  2015-08-07 17:00:00.000  null
1234  2015-08-08 08:00:00.000  2015-08-08 08:00:00.000  Weekend
```

Table structure : st_id in attendance and st_holiday table are not unique. The value will be repeated. For eg. eah st_id in st_holiday will have 20 holidays for very year i.e. st_id is repeated 20 times. In attendance table st_id will depend on no. of times student comes in and goes out of classroom.

```
attendance 
    -------------
    st_id         in_time              out_time      time_in_class
    3370    2009-10-8 11:54:0.0 2009-10-8 18:1:0.0  6.11666666666667
    4209            0                     0               0
    4225            0                     0               0
    3779    2009-10-8 14:27:0.0 2009-10-9 0:5:0.0   9.63333333333333


    hol_list
    -------------
    id           hol_date          type        desc             holiday_type

    229 2007-04-06 00:00:00.000     1       Good Friday             Holiday
    231 2007-05-01 00:00:00.000     1       International Labor Day Holiday
    233 2007-07-04 00:00:00.000     1       Independence Day        Holiday
    234 2007-07-07 00:00:00.000     1       Weekend                 Weekend


    st_holiday
    -------------
    st_id   holiday     holiday_type
     9201   39965         Holiday
     9201   39961         Holiday
     9201   39951         Holiday
     9201   39942         Holiday
     9201   39935         Weekend
     9201   39927         Holiday
```

Comment: Could you provide the table structures, some sample data and expected result?

Comment: How does `st_holiday` relate with `hol_list`? What's `holiday`  data type?

Comment: hol_list primary key id is mapped as holiday in st_holiday table.

Comment: With that said, all records in `st_holiday` are also in `hol_list` table? How do you determine the `holiday_type`?

Comment: Yes. but not mapped to students..

Comment: So what's wrong with your first query? And what do you want to achieve?

Comment: First query gives me only in and out_time only on a holiday.. I need the students in and out time for all days and those corresponding to a holiday should be marked as Holiday separately. For regular weekday attendance, Holiday_type will be null, but attendance for Saturday/Sunday Holiday_type should be Weekend, 4th July- Independance day.. etc.

Comment: And is `holiday_type` in `st_holiday`?

Comment: No. Holiday_type is not in st_holiday.. It has holiday column which is ID of Hol_list table.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand. Can you provide data for each table, complete with the relevant columns. Also, have you tried @rgstamayo's answer?

Comment: Ok. Will try below solution and revert.

Comment: I suggest you create a [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c2bd/3) that way is easy to reproduce your issue and give you a proper solution.

Comment: When people ask for table structures, it's a *lot* better if you provide it as `CREATE TABLE` statements (you can generate these by right-clicking the tables in SSMS and choosing Script Table As -> Create To and picking where you want to send it). That way, other people can just copy & paste those definitions straight into their SQL Servers and be a lot closer to being ready to help you out. Similarly, `INSERT` statements are a great way to present sample data - because, again, we can just copy & paste that into SSMS and be ready to work on the actual query. Rather than having to interpret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample query and explanation. For your first question, kindly give this a try:

```
select a.student_id, a.in_time, a.out_time, b.holiday_type
from attendance a 
left join st_holiday b on a.st_id = b.st_id
inner join hol_list c on a.date = c.hol_date
```

Comment: I tried your query, it is still giving only holiday in and out times. But I am getting multiple rows of same data.

Comment: Table struct : attendance 
-------------
st_id  in_time  out_time time_in_class


hol_list
-------------
id  hol_date  type desc


st_holiday
-------------
st_id  holiday  holiday_type

Comment: @razor The table structure is confusing, can you give sample data for each table?

Comment: I modified your query like this : select a.student_id, a.in_time, a.out_time, b.holiday_type
from attendance a 
left join st_holiday b on a.st_id = b.st_id
inner join hol_list c on c.id = b.holiday..   This gives me holiday b.desc repetitively... but in & out times are correct.